# How to Save and Load Data from a File into a Struct in Object?

Tags: c

I'm creating a Task Manager in which I'll store Tasks and Employees.

I have two structs.
When I open the application, I want to copy the data from the file into the struct, and when I shut the program, I want to save the data back into the file.

The Save Data function is functional, however, the Load Data function is not.

Also, even if the data isn't loaded into struct when the file is open, when I close the program, it saves the data and doesn't overwrite it.

***Function to Load Data from the file***

```
void GetData(){
    FILE *fptr = fopen("Manager_Data.txt", "r");
    for (int i = 0;i < TAM_EMP; i++) {
        fscanf(fptr, "%d,%s,%s,%d,%s,%s,%s,%d\n", &employees[i].ID, employees[i].name, employees[i].date, &employees[i].phone, employees[i].email, employees[i].local, employees[i].depart, &employees[i].availability);
    }
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

***Function to Save the Data into file***

```
void saveData(){
    FILE *fptr = fopen("Manager_Data.txt", "w");
    for (int i = 0;i < TAM_EMP; i++) {
        fprintf(fptr, "%d,%s,%s,%d,%s,%s,%s,%d\n", employees[i].ID, employees[i].name, employees[i].date, employees[i].phone, employees[i].email, employees[i].local, employees[i].depart, employees[i].availability);
    }
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows the problems of loading and saving, along with a small sample file content, say 2 or 3 records.

Comment: If you `fprintf(ptr, "%s,%s\n", "hello", "world")` the file will have one line, which is `hello,world`. When you `fscanf(ptr, "%s,%s", str1, str2)` the first string will contain `hello,world` and the second string will contain nothing. That's because `"%s"` in a `fscanf` won't stop until it either reaches the end of the line, or it finds a whitespace character (e.g. space or TAB).

Comment: You never check that `fscanf` reads the correct number of items, *always* check this. A fuller example might also reveal a potential problem if a name has two words. This will upset the reading with `%s` but not the writing with `%s`.

Comment: @user3386109's point is good: `scanf` with `%s` does not stop at a comma, but it does stop at whitespace.

Comment: Maybe `%[^,]` instead of `%s` in the `fscanf()` call? And, maybe some limit on the length of a string, too, to avoid overflowing the receiving buffer. AND, the `\n` in the format string for reading is also either unnecessary or wrong...

Comment: Parsing a comma separated values (CSV) file takes a bit of work. One way to do it is read the entire line with `fgets` and then use `strtok` to separate the fields, using the commas as the delimiter.

Comment: There are very many previous questions about reading CSV files. it is not a trivial exercise.

Comment: @user3386109 Wrong. CSV files can contain empty fields (eg "foo,,,bar"). `strtok()` will return "bar" as the 2nd field. Further, CSV files use double quotes to 'hide' embedded commas (eg: "... ,"$25,147.00",,,") `strtok()` is NOT the solution for CSV files.

Comment: If the struct is defined with `char` arrays, not pointers, for the strings, you could use `fwrite()` and `fread()` and "wb"/"rb" in `fopen()` to deal with the records as records instead of strings of text. Doing so would allow you to save/load in bulk instead of piecemeal 'looping' and dealing with field separators.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Wrong. That's really bad advice, because it means that even the slightest change to the structure invalidates all existing data files. It creates a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many problems with

```
fscanf(fptr, "%d,%s,%s,%d,%s,%s,%s,%d\n", 
    &employees[i].ID, employees[i].name, employees[i].date, 
    &employees[i].phone, employees[i].email, employees[i].local, 
    employees[i].depart, &employees[i].availability);
```

- `%s` will not stop when it reads `','`.  To stop at a `','`, use `" %[^,]"`.
- `%s` does not limit the input to the buffer size.  Use a *width* like `"%99s"` for a `char buffer[100]`.
- Code does not test the return value of `fscanf()`.  Without checking that it is 8, in this case, following code does not know scan was successful.

---

Better to forego `fscanf()` and use `fgets()` to read a *line* of input into a *string* and then parse the string.

Like other issues, yet post is scant.

Comment: I end up makin a fgets(); and fprintf() for each. It's working, my only problem now is to get the data from the file into the struct, since it get's corrupted

Comment: @AntónioVelez Post a _line_ of sample data and the definition of employees type.

Comment: struct Employees{
    int ID;
    int availability;
    char name[TAM_NAME];
    char date[TAM_DATE];
    int phone;
    char email[TAM_EMAIL];
    char local[TAM_LOCAL];
    char depart[TAM_DEPART];
};

Comment: António Velez, please post a line of sample data.  Best to add that and the struct definition to the question.

Answer (score 0):

***Function to remove "\n" when getting data from file***

```
    void RemoveNewLine(char *str)
{
    int len = strlen(str);
    if (str[len - 1] == '\n')
    {
        str[len - 1] = '\0';
    }
}
```

***Import Employees Data from file to Struct***

```
void EmployeesGetData()
{
    FILE *Employees_Data;
    Employees_Data = fopen("Employees_Data.txt", "r");

    if (Employees_Data == NULL)
    {
        printf("Erro:O ficheiro 'Employees_Data.txt não foi encontrado'\n");
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < TAM_EMP; ++i)
    {
        if (fscanf(Employees_Data, "%d\n", &employees[i].ID) == EOF)
        {
            break;
        }
        fscanf(Employees_Data, "%d\n", &employees[i].availability);
        fgets(employees[i].name, TAM_NAME, Employees_Data);
        RemoveNewLine(employees[i].name);
        fgets(employees[i].date, TAM_DATE, Employees_Data);
        RemoveNewLine(employees[i].date);
        fscanf(Employees_Data, "%d\n", &employees[i].phone);
        fgets(employees[i].email, TAM_EMAIL, Employees_Data);
        RemoveNewLine(employees[i].email);
        fgets(employees[i].local, TAM_LOCAL, Employees_Data);
        RemoveNewLine(employees[i].local);
        fgets(employees[i].depart, TAM_DEPART, Employees_Data);
        RemoveNewLine(employees[i].depart);
    }
    fclose(Employees_Data);
}
```

***Save Employees Data from struct to file***

```
void EmployeesSaveData()
{
    FILE *Employees_Data = fopen("Employees_Data.txt", "w");

    if (Employees_Data == NULL)
    {
        printf("Erro:O ficheiro 'Employees_Data.txt não foi encontrado!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < TAM_EMP; ++i)
    {
        if (employees[i].availability == 1)
        {
            fprintf(Employees_Data, "%d\n", employees[i].ID);
            fprintf(Employees_Data, "%d\n", employees[i].availability);
            fprintf(Employees_Data, "%s\n", employees[i].name);
            fprintf(Employees_Data, "%s\n", employees[i].date);
            fprintf(Employees_Data, "%d\n", employees[i].phone);
            fprintf(Employees_Data, "%s\n", employees[i].email);
            fprintf(Employees_Data, "%s\n", employees[i].local);
            fprintf(Employees_Data, "%s\n", employees[i].depart);
        }
    }
    fclose(Employees_Data);
}
```